# Angular multiselect menu with arbitrary bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select-menu

How can I bind a select menu to a bunch of arbitrary options in a select menu.

I tied this:

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
    <option ng-model="some.prop">Average</option>
    <option ng-model="foo.bar.baz">Minimum</option>
    <option ng-model="another">Maximum</option>
</select>
```

But it doesn't work, using `ng-selected` works, but only 1 way (i.e. doesn't change the variable when selecting/unselecting an option.

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
    <option ng-selected="some.prop">Average</option>
    <option ng-selected="foo.bar.baz">Minimum</option>
    <option ng-selected="another">Maximum</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting/deselecting `<option>` items in a `<select>`, only the ng-model attached to the `<select>` will change. Using ng-selected with `<option>` elements doesn't change that: the property specified by ng-selected is read-only.

Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/zilmbj77WqOlXNTI6b10?p=preview

Perhaps you can represent this scenario better using a group of check-boxes? Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="some.prop" ng-true-value="a" ng-false-value="b" />  
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="foo.bar.baz" ng-true-value="foo" ng-false-value="bar" />  
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="another" ng-true-value="0" ng-false-value="1" />
```

To accomplish a bi-directionally bound list of choices, you could use a custom drop-down with multiple checkboxes, like this one: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

Comment: I specifically want a multiselect not checkboxes. Also what do you menu "changes in value"? A multiselect has multiple values that can be toggled.

Comment: @Petah Correct, a multiselect can toggle multiple values, be it will only update the mutliselect's own ng-model. One way to implement read/write binding to multiple arbitrary $scope properties, is by using a custom drop-down of checkboxes.

Comment: @Petah, what you "specifically want" doesn't make sense (unless you care to explain your motivation). `<select multiple>` works by setting `ng-model` to be an array of `<option>` values. Your own question doesn't even specify what the value that should be set to these properties should be - is it a boolean? The checkbox approach seems the better fit for your case. If you want the look-and-feel of a select, then create a custom input control